# Gap detection between dates logic failing on first grouped record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

Before asking recently here I've managed to build a query that calculates gaps for each user log. The CTE lists each user log by their ID using ROW_NUMBER(), then in a second CTE it self joins on the ´RN id + 1´ resulting in the "recursive" calculation of the ´INIx date - FINx-1´, later I add an indicator for visual help. Running the query as-is it returns correctly almost every row, but I noticed in some cases the first sequential log is listed as ´NOSEQ´ (no sequential) because my indicator only considers ´1´ as condition to be sequential.

[image: CTE RESULT]

Where RN = 5 it's sequential but since it calculates itself with the following log it doesn't meet the requirement. I don't know if I'm missing something or I have to start all over... Any help on my query logic it's appreciated. (Consider I'm limited to SQL Server 2008 sintax)

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    select * from sysobjects where name='INF_LIC' and xtype='U'
) CREATE TABLE INF_LIC (
    [PER_PRO_ID_HR_INI_FIN] NVARCHAR(57)
);
INSERT INTO INF_LIC VALUES
    (N'201811;P1;2018-11-23 00:00:00.000;2018-11-23 00:00:00.000'),
    (N'201810;P1;2018-10-25 00:00:00.000;2018-10-26 00:00:00.000'),
    (N'201809;P1;2018-09-28 00:00:00.000;2018-09-28 00:00:00.000'),
    (N'201808;P1;2018-08-31 00:00:00.000;2018-09-05 00:00:00.000'),
    (N'201807;P1;2018-07-05 00:00:00.000;2018-07-25 00:00:00.000'),
    (N'201806;P1;2018-06-14 00:00:00.000;2018-07-04 00:00:00.000'),
    (N'201805;P1;2018-05-25 00:00:00.000;2018-06-13 00:00:00.000'),
    (N'201805;P1;2018-05-10 00:00:00.000;2018-05-24 00:00:00.000'),
    (N'201804;P1;2018-04-25 00:00:00.000;2018-05-09 00:00:00.000');

;WITH CTE AS(
    -- LIST EVERY RECORD
    SELECT ID, CAST(INI AS DATETIME) AS INI, CAST(FIN AS DATETIME) AS FIN, 
        RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CAST(FIN AS DATETIME) DESC)
    FROM INF_LIC
    WHERE PER_PRO > 201712
), CTE2 AS(
    -- CALCULATE DATEDIFF
    SELECT T.*, 
        -- DATEDIFF BETWEEN INIn - FINn-1
        DD = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,T.FIN,T2.INI) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF(DD,T2.INI,T.FIN) END
    FROM CTE 
    -- LEFT JOIN ON EQUAL ID's AND RN = RN+1
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2 ON T.RN = T2.RN + 1 AND T.ID = T2.ID AND T.RN <> T2.RN
), CTE3 AS(
    SELECT ID, INI, FIN, RN, ABS(DD) AS DD,
    -- INDICATOR, IF -1 ITS 'SEQ', NULL MARKS THE NEWEST LOG 'FIRSTLOG' ELSE IT'S NOT SEQUENTIAL
    IND = (CASE WHEN DD = -1 THEN 'SEQ'
        WHEN DD = 0 THEN 'FIRSTLOG'
        ELSE 'NOSEQ'
        END)
    FROM CTE2
), CTE4 AS(
    SELECT ID, INI, FIN, RN, DD, IND
    FROM CTE3
    GROUP BY ID, INI, FIN, RN, DD, IND 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE4
ORDER BY ID, RN ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear why you believe record 5 to be sequential. The SQL in the question implies that the definition of sequential is that the previous record's `ini` is 1 day apart from this record's `fin`, which is true.

However, that's a suspicious definition given those column names. I suspect you want to define `ind` such that it's sequential when this record's `fin` is 1 day apart from the next record's `ini`. If that's true, then you probably want to do this:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    -- LIST EVERY RECORD
    SELECT ID, CAST(INI AS DATETIME) AS INI, CAST(FIN AS DATETIME) AS FIN, 
        RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CAST(FIN AS DATETIME) DESC)
    FROM INF_LIC
    WHERE PER_PRO > 201712
), CTE2 AS(
    -- CALCULATE DATEDIFF
    SELECT T.*, 
        -- DATEDIFF BETWEEN INIn - FINn-1
        DD = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,T2.FIN,T.INI) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF(DD,T.INI,T2.FIN) END
    FROM CTE T
    -- LEFT JOIN ON EQUAL ID's AND RN = RN+1
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2 ON T.RN = T2.RN - 1 AND T.ID = T2.ID
), CTE3 AS(
    SELECT ID, INI, FIN, RN, ABS(DD) AS DD,
    -- INDICATOR, IF -1 ITS 'SEQ', NULL MARKS THE NEWEST LOG 'FIRSTLOG' ELSE IT'S NOT SEQUENTIAL
    IND = (CASE WHEN DD in (0, -1) THEN 'SEQ'
        WHEN RN = 1 THEN 'FIRSTLOG'
        ELSE 'NOSEQ'
        END)
    FROM CTE2
), CTE4 AS(
    SELECT ID, INI, FIN, RN, DD, IND
    FROM CTE3
    GROUP BY ID, INI, FIN, RN, DD, IND 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE4
ORDER BY ID, RN ASC
```

Where the pertinent changes are:

```
LEFT JOIN CTE T2 ON T.RN = T2.RN - 1 AND T.ID = T2.ID
```

That join is now `T2.RN` minus one: you need to subtract the next record's row number to get at it, not add, and:

```
IND = (CASE WHEN DD in (0, -1) THEN 'SEQ'
        WHEN RN = 1 THEN 'FIRSTLOG'
        ELSE 'NOSEQ'
        END)
```

Since you are already row numbering, you might as well use the obvious definition of FIRSTLOG. Since this join order is now backwards from the original assumption, a `DD` of 0 now means that it's the last record, not the first, so it slightly expands the definition of SEQ.

Comment: Thanks, I did apply your changes but the results are still the same, notice the log starting the 05/07/2018 it's followed by RN= 6 with 04/07/2018, the are sequential but since it calculates the row above it displays 37...